# Internet "Lags" when using DHCP

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

OS: Archlinux
Relevant Package: NetworkManager

TLDW/TLDR: When using DHCP it takes about 16 seconds to complete 3 pings to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). But when using a Static IP it takes about 2 seconds.

Recently I've been noticing some lag in general browsing. there's a delay of a few seconds before a page starts loading.
when i googled the issue i got a lot of results that said "slow with static ip but fast with dhcp/dynamic ip".
Just as a sanity test i opened nmtui and changed my ipv4 from automatic to manual and set the ip, default gateway and dns server. After this there was no lag. again changed it to automatic and the lag is back. I am attaching a video which shows this using `ping` and `time` (not the bash built-in, but the one from pacman).

Link to Video: https://a.uguu.se/KyCeeyDw.mkv

this link expires every 24 hours. I will keep it updated.

[dhcp vs static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2dgr.gif)

Comment: oh right. i don't know why but i completely forgot about dns servers. for some reason the default dns servers were lagging. once i switched to google's dns everything was fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHCP isn’t really involved in your network communication. It is only used to initially configure your network connectivity. (And again after the configuration expires.)

DHCP is commonly used to get the following options:

- IP address
- Subnet mask
- Default gateway address
- DNS server address(es)
- DNS search domain

That means you should check what the DHCP configuration is (`ip addr`, `resolvectl`, `/etc/resolv.conf`…) and how it compares to your manual configuration. Whatever is making the difference is there.

---

You indicate that the DHCP-provided DNS server was slow. This is unfortunately somewhat common. As an alternative one could use Google DNS, Cloudflare DNS, OpenDNS or any other public recursive DNS server.

Comment: changing the dns solved it. the default one's are/were having issues recently